# Spring Transaction Annotations vs Tx Namespace: Which is used more?

Tags: spring, transactions

I'm studying both of these approaches to include transactions in my Spring application. As for now, I prefer using annotations, as opposed to the tx namespace. The reason is that it sort of clears up the XML/complexity. But this is just my opinion.

I have not had a chance to see what current Spring practitioners use for transactions. Which one is now the preferred approach, and why?

In other words, what are the pros and cons of each approach that ultimately justify the use of one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use annotations for marking transactions, not because of the ease of configuration or because of concerns about purity of coupling to Spring, but rather because it is typically the case that the code inside the method cannot work correctly without a transaction in place: the annotation is indicating something functional about the implementation as opposed to the way in which the code is managed (which would belong to the Spring configuration file).

Comment: I understand. But do you think that there are times when using tx would be more effective? Also, is it common for practitioners to use both approaches in a single project? I personally prefer the annotations simply because of the simplicity for now; I've been doing all I can in order to get rid of XML (i.e. pointcuts). But I also want to make sure that my studies are geared towards what is considered best practices.

Comment: @user1079776: Best practices are flexible, as they typically include a large dose of “well, it depends on what you're actually doing”. The problem with annotations for these things is that you can't change them so easily when doing testing; that's when the XML configuration comes into its own. But for transactions specifically? Annotations make perfect sense there, as that makes it easy to identify the places where the transaction aspect is applied. (Explicit beats implicit when it comes to maintenance.)

Answer (score 3):

### `<tx:advice>` / `<tx:attributes>` / `<tx:method>`

#### Pros

- No Spring-dependencies in your code
- Very flexible, e.g. make all methods with `get` prefix transactional but read-only
- Easily applying transaction demarcation into wide range of beans

#### Cons

- cumbersome and hard to maintain XML
- more XML
- ...even more XML

### `@Transactional` and `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

#### Pros

- Dead-simple, just add annotation over class or method
- One line of XML (or even none with `@EnableTransactionManagement`) and it just works

#### Cons

- Spring dependency in your code
- Not possible to apply more general rules, like: *all classes within a package that end with `Dao`*